# ReactJS - popover onClick insde data-content doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, popover, bootstrap-popover

I'm using ReactJS and I'm trying to do a delete confirm popover and it works but when I click on "delete" doesn't work at all!

I'm using a button and inside I have an Icon and when click should popover its data-content, and it does! but the onClick inside doesn't work, maybe it's the way that I'm writing it? Have no idea what's going on

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you, hope you can help me!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faTrashAlt, faEdit, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import NewTask from '../NewTask/NewTask';

import './Tasks.css';



 class Tasks extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectId: props._id,
            project: props.project,
            tasks: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`/dashboard/project/${this.props.projectId}/tasks`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            }).then(task => {
                this.setState({
                    tasks: task.tasks
                })
            }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

    appendTask = task => {
        let tasks = this.state.tasks;
        tasks.push(task);
        this.setState({tasks});
    }

    removeTask = taskId => {
        let tasks = this.state.tasks;

        let taskToDel = tasks.find(function(element){ 
            if(element._id === taskId) {
                return element;
            }
        });

        if(taskToDel) {
            // Find index of task to remove
            const index = tasks.indexOf(taskToDel);
            // If task index is found remove task from array
            if(index != -1)
                tasks.splice(index, 1);

            this.setState({tasks});

        }

    }


    deleteTaskOnDb = task => {
        let data = {taskId: task._id};

        fetch(`/dashboard/project/${this.props.projectId}/tasks/delete`, {
            method: 'delete',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            //if(response.status === 200)
                return response.json()
        }).then(taskId => {
            this.removeTask(taskId);
        }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }


    render() {

//POPOVER FUNCTION HERE

        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
          })
//POPOVER FUNCTION HERE

        const fontawesomeiconStyle = {
            fontSize: '1em',
            color: '#bd822a',
            textAlign: 'center'
        }

        const listStyle = {
            display:'flex', 
            flexFlow: 'row wrap',
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        }

        const { tasks } = this.state;
        return (


            <div>
                <ul className="task-list">
                    {tasks.map(task =>
                <li key={task._id} style={listStyle}> <div>
                {task.tasktitle} 
                <br/>
                <p style={{fontSize: '10px', color: '#a2a2a2'}}>{moment(task.created).format('MMM DD YY, h:mm A')} </p>  

                </div>
              <div>
                <p style={{fontSize: '12px', color: '#a2a2a2'}}>{task.taskcomment}</p>
              </div>
                   <div>

    //BUTTON HERE

              <button type="button" className="example-popover btn--delete button--tasks" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Are you sure? <button type='button' className='btn--delete button--tasks' onClick='{() => this.deleteTaskOnDb(task)}'> Delete</button>">
                   <FontAwesomeIcon style={fontawesomeiconStyle} icon={faTimes} />
               </button>

    //BUTTON HERE
                    </div>
                </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
                {this.props.project &&
                    this.props.project._id &&
                    <NewTask projectId={this.props.project._id} appendTask={this.appendTask}/>
                }
          </div> 
        );
    }
}

export default Tasks;
```

[image: An example of my Task and its popover]

[image]

Comment: Show the console error @Ana Fig

Comment: @PassionInfinite it's weird but I don't get any error :/

Comment: Can you log data in the `deleteTaskOnDb` to check wheather the click is invoking the function and if it is then we have the data.

Comment: Your issue has something to do with data-toggle, I have a similar issue where the onClick react would only function once due to the data-toggle from bootstrap.